# Check whether a street address exists in R

Tags: r, google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to write a simple code to check if a street address exists:

In my first try I put the write address and it gives me the correct adress:

```
addr <- '2147 Newhall Street,Santa Clara,CA 95050'  
url = paste('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=',  addr,'&sensor=false',sep='')  
doc = xmlTreeParse(url) 
root = xmlRoot(doc) 
lat = xmlValue(root[['result']][['geometry']][['location']][['lat']]) 
long = xmlValue(root[['result']][['geometry']][['location']][['lng']]) 
lat
"37.3386004"
long
"-121.9405759"
```

But if I write a wrong street address it's still giving me co-ordinates:

```
addr <- 'xyz,Santa Clara,CA 95050'  # set your address here
url = paste('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=',      addr,'&sensor=false',sep='')    
doc = xmlTreeParse(url) 
root = xmlRoot(doc) 
lat = xmlValue(root[['result']][['geometry']][['location']][['lat']]) 
long = xmlValue(root[['result']][['geometry']][['location']][['lng']]) 
lat
"37.3539663"
long
"-121.9529992"
```

I'm sure the street address above does not exist, but I'm still getting some coordinates. Is there anyway I can return an NA value or some flag if there is no valid street address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a nice wrapper of the Google Maps geocoding API in the `ggmap` package. If you set its `output` parameter to `more`, it will return a `loctype` which indicates if the address is precisely matched (`rooftop`) or an approximation (`approximate`, `range_interpolated`, `geometric_center`). See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?csw=1#Results) for further detail.

```
library(ggmap)
addr <- '2147 Newhall Street,Santa Clara,CA 95050' 
geocode(addr, 'more')
# Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2147%20Newhall%20Street,Santa%20Clara,CA%2095050&sensor=false
#         lon     lat           type loctype                                     address    north
# 1 -121.9406 37.3386 street_address rooftop 2147 newhall st, santa clara, ca 95050, usa 37.33995
#      south      east      west street_number          route    locality
# 1 37.33725 -121.9392 -121.9419          2147 Newhall Street Santa Clara
#   administrative_area_level_2 administrative_area_level_1       country postal_code
# 1          Santa Clara County                  California United States       95050

addr <- 'xyz,Santa Clara,CA 95050'
geocode(addr, 'more')
# Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=xyz,Santa%20Clara,CA%2095050&sensor=false
#        lon      lat        type     loctype                    address    north    south
# 1 -121.953 37.35397 postal_code approximate santa clara, ca 95050, usa 37.37448 37.32314
#        east      west postal_code    locality administrative_area_level_2
# 1 -121.9309 -121.9703       95050 Santa Clara          Santa Clara County
#   administrative_area_level_1       country
# 1                  California United States
```

Comment: Oh Ok got it. I can then just write a condition to check if the loctype is approximate.